# How to coverr java code to objective C using "US-ASCII" & HmacSHA256?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public static String sign(String path, String accesKeyId, Long expires, String key) throws Exception {
 String canonical = "GET\n\n\n" + expires + "\n" + path;
 byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
 Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
 hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256"));
 byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.doFinal(canonical.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 String signatureBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes), "US-ASCII");
 String signature = URLEncoder.encode(signatureBase64, "UTF-8");
return signature;
}
```

**Input Parameters :**

- path : /1.0/customer/abc@abc.com
- accesKeyId :432QQYKATPUBUNHESSPDTQU
- expires : 1532405086
- key :bzjG1Z5c5+4on14I0zJaJFAzTs1302Ya40A6JhI2uNY=

**Output should be :** mWSy2mKRgG1MXeNVC1dBs6lbtx5c1lxvSy919DW5Sow%3D

Please let me know as soon as possible.

Here is my best attempt:

```
-(NSString *)getKey:(NSString*)path withAccesKeyId:(NSString*)accesKeyId withExpireTime:(long)expires withSecretKey:(NSString*)key{

    NSString *data=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\n\n\n%ld\n%@",expires,path];
    NSData* bytes = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *base64Data = [bytes base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
    NSData* conicalData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, base64Data.bytes, base64Data.length, conicalData.bytes, conicalData.length, hash.mutableBytes);
    NSString *signature = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    return signature;
```

}

I have also tried using below code :

```
NSString *data=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\n\n\n%ld\n%@",expires,path];
NSData* bytes = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *strBaseKey=[bytes base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];;

const char *cKey  = [strBaseKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                      length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

NSString *signature = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

return signature;
```

**But i got this output for both way ** :+CYVGnQsfZ3jHsmlo39uEHEPzGGeHlTDFbJMw5K3g8c=

Comment: We're not here to just give you code. StackOverflow is not a free code translation service. Try it yourself and if it doesn't work, come back.

Comment: hmm - more information please - soon as possible

Comment: @ArtjomB. I know this is not free code translation service. But a hub of good developers that's why i have put this issue here. I have tried a lot but not getting exact output. Please if you have any solution then suggest.

Comment: @MrT which kind of extra information you need. ? i have mention the input parameters and output and java code..  Have i miss anything ?

Comment: Voted for close. But [this will help you for sure](http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#objc) . *go on top and click on language you need*

Comment: [visit this for detailed google result](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mac.getinstance(%20hmacsha256%20)%20for%20ios)

Comment: You need to provide your best attempt code along with a description of the error/problem you have.

Comment: @zaph Please check i have mention my best attempt

Comment: I have voted to reopen. If the question does not get enough reopen votes in an hour or so you will need to create a new question because answers can not be added to a closed question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is close.

- The first error is not handling the Base64 `key` properly
- The second error is simply not URL encoding the Base64 character "="

Here is my example interspersed with the original Java code and NSLog statements:

```
NSString *path    = @"/1.0/customer/abc@abc.com";
UInt64    expires = 1532405086;
NSString *key     = @"bzjG1Z5c5+4on14I0zJaJFAzTs1302Ya40A6JhI2uNY=";
// NSString *accesKeyId = @"432QQYKATPUBUNHESSPDTQU"; // Unused

// String canonical = "GET\n\n\n" + expires + "\n" + path;
NSString *canonicalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\n\n\n%lld\n%@", expires, path];
NSData   *canonicalData   = [canonicalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"canonicalData: %@", canonicalData);

// byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
NSLog(@"keyData: %@", keyData);

// Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
// hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256"));
// byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.doFinal(canonical.getBytes("UTF-8"));
NSMutableData *signatureData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256,
       keyData.bytes, keyData.length,
       canonicalData.bytes, canonicalData.length,
       signatureData.mutableBytes);
NSLog(@"signatureData: %@", signatureData);

// String signatureBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes), "US-ASCII");
NSString *signatureBase64 = [signatureData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"signatureBase64: %@", signatureBase64);

// String signature = URLEncoder.encode(signatureBase64, "UTF-8");
NSCharacterSet *base64Characterset = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+/="] invertedSet];
NSString *signature = [signatureBase64 stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:base64Characterset];
NSLog(@"signature: %@", signature);
```

Output:

> canonicalData: <4745540a 0a0a3135 33323430 35303836 0a2f312e 302f6375 73746f6d 65722f61 62634061 62632e63 6f6d>
>   keyData: <6f38c6d5 9e5ce7ee 289f5e08 d3325a24 50334ecd 77d3661a e3403a26 1236b8d6>
>   signatureData: <9964b2da 6291806d 4c5de355 0b5741b3 a95bb71e 5cd65c6f 4b2f75f4 35b94a8c>
>   signatureBase64: mWSy2mKRgG1MXeNVC1dBs6lbtx5c1lxvSy919DW5Sow=
>   signature: mWSy2mKRgG1MXeNVC1dBs6lbtx5c1lxvSy919DW5Sow%3D

Comment: @ChatApp Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best.  [See this page for more detail](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).